# How to break/pause reading of an image?

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

I am creating a panel which is showing large image. I am using `ImageIO.read(URL)` method to show the image. Now I have to add functionality to break or pause the reading process of the given image URL.

How can I do this?

```
BufferedImage image = null;
URL urlImage = new URL(surl);
image = ImageIO.read(urlImage);
```

Comment: *"add functionality to break or pause the reading"*  `ImageIO.read()` is a blocking method so I don't like your chances.  OTOH this seems a strange requirement.  What is the feature you are trying to implement by doing this?  I have possible answers centered around the `InputStream` or a `MediaTracker`, but to narrow it down, try to fill in the use-case or feature of this functionality.

Comment: I want to create a cloud application where my image file is at the cloud and that is big in size like 10-20mb and once I started to read that file, I have not control to stop that and I do not want to wait for downloading complete file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll definitely need another thread from which you can close the `InputStream` which `ImageIO.read` is reading from. So, first of all, you need to redesign your code:

```
final InputStream stream = new URL(surl).openStream();
// find a way to push the 'stream' reference to the other thread
final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream); // this will block
```

In the other thread, you'll have to call `stream.close()`.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be any way to do it out of the box. What you could do is, put this in a seperate thread and stop or interrupt it.

Just keep in mind, `Thread.stop()` is marked as deprecated for a good reason and think of what memory leaks might occur. Btw. why do you need to add such functionality?

Comment: I suppose OP wants the end-user to be able to stop or cancel a download.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Then this would be a solution I guess.

Comment: calling Thread.stop() is never a solution, especially if it's doing I/O.

Comment: As I said, he should be aware of memory leaks and other issues, using that.

Comment: Being aware of issues of `Thread.stop` entails not using it. Its only possible usage is in scenarios where stopping immediatly trumps every other aspect, like system stability, consistency of the JVM, etc. Basically, once you `stop` a thread, it'd better be the last thing you do before shutting down the whole JVM.